# Change this number character into a checkbox inside a table on angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox

I have this html code which uses angularjs to display contents in a table.

```
<div ng-controller="CheckCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover data-table sort display">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="Serial_">
                Serial
            </th>
            <th class="Name_">
                Name
            </th>
            <th class="ID_">
                ID
            </th>
            <th class="On_off_">
                On/off
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in check_items">
            <td>{{item.SERIAL}}</td>
            <td>{{item.NAME}}</td>
            <td>{{item.ID}}</td>
            <td>{{item.ON_OFF}}</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The webpage looks like this;

[image]

Here is the controller code.

```
.controller('CheckCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'configuration', 
    function ($scope, $http, $configuration) {
        var url_api = $configuration.host + "cloe/webroot/cloe-cloud/app/API.json";
        $http.get(url_api).success(function(data)
        {
            $scope.check_items = data;
        });
```

I would like to change the On/Off columns number character into a checkbox. If the number character is '0', the checkbox is unchecked. If the number character is '1', the checkbox is checked.

I am using angularjs v1 and twitter bootstrap.

EDIT: Sorry, I realized that my checkbox value is a character, not a number. They are '0', '1' and not 0, 1.

Comment: try this  ng-checked="item.ON_OFF==0" by changing the input to check box.if u can make a plunker for us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.check_items = [ {
       'SERIAL':12345,
       'NAME': 'ANil Kumar Ram',
       'ID' : 1,
       'ON_OFF': '1'
    },{
       'SERIAL':6453,
       'NAME': 'Rohan Ram',
       'ID' : 2,
       'ON_OFF': '0'
    },{
       'SERIAL':732,
       'NAME': 'Sunil Ram',
       'ID' : 3,
       'ON_OFF': '0'
    },{
       'SERIAL':1261,
       'NAME': 'Ram Jitesh',
       'ID' : 4,
       'ON_OFF': '1'
    }]
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover data-table sort display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="Serial_">
                Serial
            </th>
            <th class="Name_">
                Name
            </th>
            <th class="ID_">
                ID
            </th>
            <th class="On_off_">
                On/off
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in check_items">
            <td>{{item.SERIAL}}</td>
            <td>{{item.NAME}}</td>
            <td>{{item.ID}}</td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.ON_OFF == '1'"></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a problem. I just realized the checkbox values are in string. They are 'ON_OFF': '1', not 'ON_OFF': 1. I will change the question details accordingly.

Comment: in that case you have to compare string with '=='

Comment: i ve modified snippet as u are using ON_OFF as string.. if this help you can accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-checked='{{item.ON_OFF == 1}}'>
```

Think that should do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="{{item.ON_OFF}}" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">
```

`ng-true-value` the value that will set the input checked
`ng-false-value="0"` the value that will set the input unchecked

Angular Documentation 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: Syntax correction <input type="checkbox" ng-model="{{item.ON_OFF}}" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">

Comment: can you edit your answer with correct syntax mentioned in comment 1 that would help others

Comment: No problem, as requested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a problem. I just realized the checkbox values are in string. They are `'ON_OFF': '1'`, not `'ON_OFF': 1`. I will change the question details accordingly.

Comment: Yes, just updated the code snippet to include '', like so ng-true-value="'1'". You should be good.